# Getting the moving median from an array

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to get the moving median from an array. I am getting error with the code below and I will appreciate your help for a solution.

```
 import java.util.*;
    public class Movmedian {
        /**
         * The add number method
         */
        public static void addNumber(int num, PriorityQueue<Integer> lowers, PriorityQueue<Integer> highers) {
            if(lowers.size() == 0 || num < lowers.peek()) {
                lowers.add(num);
            } else {
                highers.add(num);
            }
        }
        /**
         * The rebalance method
         */
        public static void rebalance(PriorityQueue<Integer> lowers, PriorityQueue<Integer> highers) {
            PriorityQueue<Integer> biggerHeap = lowers.size() > highers.size() ? lowers : highers;
            PriorityQueue<Integer> smallerHeap = lowers.size() > highers.size() ? highers : lowers;
            if(biggerHeap.size() - smallerHeap.size() >= 2) {
                smallerHeap.add(biggerHeap.poll());
            }
        }
        /**
         * The get median method
         */
        public static double getMedian(PriorityQueue<Integer> lowers, PriorityQueue<Integer> highers) {
            PriorityQueue<Integer> biggerHeap = lowers.size() > highers.size() ? lowers : highers;
            PriorityQueue<Integer> smallerHeap = lowers.size() > highers.size() ? highers : lowers;
            if(biggerHeap.size() == smallerHeap.size()) {
                return ((double)biggerHeap.peek() + smallerHeap.peek())/2;
            } else {
                return biggerHeap.peek();
            }
        }
        /**
         * The get medians method
         * @param array
         */
        public static double[] getMedians(int[] array) {
            PriorityQueue<Integer> lowHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>(){
                public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
                    return -1 * a.compareTo(b);
                }
            });
            PriorityQueue<Integer> highHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
            double[] medians = new double[array.length];
            /**
             * The loop
             */
            for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
                int number = (int) array[i];
                addNumber(number,lowHeap,highHeap);
                rebalance(lowHeap,highHeap);
                medians[i] = getMedian(lowHeap,highHeap);
                System.out.println(medians[i]);//this is the running median
            }
            return medians;
        }
        /**
         * The main
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] adio = {6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7};
            Scanner ini = new Scanner(String.valueOf(adio));
            int n = ini.nextInt();
            int[] a = new int[n];
            for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
                a[i] = ini.nextInt();
            }
            getMedians(a);

        }
    }
```

I expect to get the output 12.0  8.0  5.0  4.5  5.0  6.0
but am getting error in the code.  How do I modify it to get the expected result using an array.  When I use the correction made by @xtratic I get the answer 6.0
9.0
6.0
5.5
5.0
5.5
6.0

```
When  I use scanner method below I obtain the correct answer which is 12.0 8.0 5.0 4.5 5.0 6.0
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = in.nextInt();
      int[] a = new int[n];
      for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
       a[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

            getMedians(a);
        }

When I modify code below to use array
public static void main(String[] args) {
           double [] adio = {6.0, 12.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 8.0, 7.0 };
           double[] a = adio.clone();
            getMedians(a);
        }
I get the 6.0 9.0 6.0 5.5 5.0 5.5 6.0 
Please how do I modify this code using array to get the correct answer 
12.0 8.0 5.0 4.5 5.0 6.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Why `int[] adio = {...}; Scanner ini = new Scanner(String.valueOf(adio));` ? I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing..

Comment: Please when you get an "error in the code", _post_ the error...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at kmeans.Movmedian.main(Movmedian.java:69)  that is the error

Comment: How do I correct this error and get the desirable result. thanks @xtratic @ Nexevis

Comment: when I use scanner to type in the numbers I get the desirable result withScanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        getMedians(a);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out how to get the moving median from an array. I am getting error with the code below and I will appreciate your help for a solution. `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117) at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076) at kmeans.Movmedian.main(Movmedian.java:69)` that is the error.

Use this instead, it will clone the original list, as it looks like you were intending to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] adio = {6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7 };
    int[] a = adio.clone();
    getMedians(a);
}
```

The issue was that :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] adio = {6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7};
        // `String.valueOf(adio)` returns something like "[I@7a9273a8"
        Scanner ini = new Scanner(String.valueOf(adio));
        // `nextInt()` fails when scanning from "[I@7a9273a8"
        int n = ini.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i] = ini.nextInt();
        }
        getMedians(a);
    }
```

---

When using the `Scanner` the first int is just used to set the length of the array, it is not used as a value in the array:

```
int n = in.nextInt(); // first int
int[] a = new int[n];
for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){ // second and more ints
   a[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

But when you are passing in the array, you include the first `6` as a value in the array:

```
double [] adio = {6.0, 12.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 8.0, 7.0 };
double[] a = adio.clone();
getMedians(a);
```

Instead when passing in the array you should leave off the first `6` since it's just telling the length of the array. Do this instead:

```
//              no 6
double [] adio = {12.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 8.0, 7.0 };
double[] a = adio.clone();
getMedians(a);
```

Comment: That is giving me a different answer 6.0
9.0
6.0
5.5
5.0
5.5
6.0
when I use the Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); int n = in.nextInt(); int[] a = new int[n]; for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){ a[i] = in.nextInt(); } getMedians(a)  and type in the 6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7  it gives me the right result which is 12.0 8.0 5.0 4.5 5.0 6.0

Comment: That's a different question now. Please accept this as an answer to your first question, then ask a new question.

Comment: Hi @xtratic that is the initial question I asked.  I will have to wait another 2 days to ask a question and I need to get this sorted urgently please

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify the what it is answering; Please try to keep your questions to one question. If you add on to your question (don't remove the original question) to include *exactly* what you're doing now and what the new issue is then I might be able to help with that too but you typically shouldn't do that on SO questions.

Comment: @Jonatino Will you add on to your question to include exactly what you do now?

Comment: @Jonatino Please post the exact code you are using now, otherwise I am unable to help. The code you show now cannot possibly do what you say is happening. You say "when I type the numbers using scanner" but your code does not read anything you type.

Comment: @Jonatino I see what the issue is. However.. you unaccepted the answer to your original question? I don't feel like playing games right now, I'm withholding the new answer. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so that you can better ask questions in the future.

Comment: @Jonatino I doubt because you don't have the `Informed` badge, which you would've received if you did read the tour page entirely...

Comment: Got badge bro@xtratic

Comment: @Jonatino I have added to my answer